# How to automatically save file with Nautilus without specifying location with Firefox / Iceweael?

Tags: nautilus, firefox

I have set it to always `save file` with files of a `.xls` extension. However it always asks me for a download location. There is a script that downloads multiple files so I would prefer to avoid specifying location and for it to automatically download to the default folder.

Screenshot below:

[image: Nautilus automatically download not specify location]

I would like to skip the above step and just automatically download to the default location. Can this be done?

Comment: Did you try checking it in settings?

Comment: I checked in iceweasel settings but not in nautilus...I was not aware there is settings in nautilus...where should I check settings?

Comment: Iceweasel. There must be a checkbox in the "Downloads" section stating something like "Always ask me where to save"

Comment: Correct, edit -> preferences -> general -> downloads `save files to:`. @Amit KK thanks for your assistance. Don't know if I should close question or if you want to answer.

Comment: I've answered ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Iceweasel and press Edit->Preferences->General->Downloads and edit the field which says `save files to:`. It should save in that location